# How to configure IIS Url Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve wildcard hostname mappings in IIS 8.5. As they don't exist, I'm trying to use URL Rewrite.

I have two formats of URL,

```
<anything>-foo.mydomain.com
<anything>-bar.mydomain.com
```

I want to map these to **two** different sites in IIS, for example

```
<anything>-foo.mydomain.com --> foo.mydomain.com/<anything>
<anything>-bar.mydomain.com --> bar.mydomain.com/<anything>
```

I'm trying to configure a URL Rewrite rule at the machine level, but I've got some problem.

If I set it to `Redirect` it works. If I set it to `Rewrite` I get an IIS `404.4`.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Here are my settings:

http://cl.ly/a6tK

Answer (score 1):

You can only rewrite the URL to the same site and same application pool. For example:

http://foo.com/bar to http://foo.com/

You need to install Application Request Routing and enable Proxy. Then it will work with URL rewriting to remote servers (regardless where or what they are) since the routing will take care of that.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing